# rename files in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have folder with files named:

```
-backup- powerpoint1.ppt
-backup- powerpoint2.ppt
-backup- powerpoint3.ppt
```

I need to rename those files in the same folder to:

```
powerpoint1.ppt
powerpoint2.ppt
powerpoint3.ppt
```

I need a batch script to accomplish that.

I have searched online and came up with this so far but the values are resolving properly:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set a=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.pptx') do (
set "dt=%%i"
echo.!dt!
 set sh=!dt!
 echo.!sh!
 set "str=%sh:~12,4%"
  echo "%%i" "%str%"
  set /a a+=1
)
```

Comment: I would not extract a certain amount of characters, I would remove the constant prefix `-backup- ` like this: `set "dt=!dt:*-backup- =!"` (this is called [sub-string replacement](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html))

Comment: why don't you use delayed expansion with the `str` variable?

Comment: ...and for `sh`? And there is no need for all these interim variables (`sh`, `str`), and the counter `a`. Why are you using filter `*.pptx` when you have `*.ppt` files (according to your description)?

Comment: @aschipl....Thanks for your tip...it worked perfectly....My sample code above should have had .pptx and not .ppt...I apologize...and you are correct I do not need those extra variables sh str etc...I was trying to debug those statements one at a time...This is the final code that worked for me.......`@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set a=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.pptx') do (
set "dt=%%i"
 set "dt=!dt:*-backup-=!"
  rename "%%i" "!dt!"
  set /a a+=1
)`

Answer (score 0):

You code does not work as expected, because you missed applying [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for the interim variables `sh` and `str`. Also the extracted string portion `!sh:~12,4!` is not correct, it should read `!sh:~9!` in order to remove the `-backup-` prefix. This is the corrected code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set a=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.pptx') do (
    set "dt=%%i"
    echo/!dt!
    set sh=!dt!
    echo/!sh!
    set "str=!sh:~9!"
    ECHO ren "%%i" "!str!"
    set /a a+=1
)
```

Actually I would not extract certain character positions, but I would remove the constant prefix `-backup-` by [sub-string replacement](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html). And you do not need the interim variables `sh` and `str`, neither do you need the counter `a`. So I would do it like this:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.pptx') do (
    set "dt=%%i"
    set "dt=!dt:*-backup- =!"
    ECHO ren "%%i" "!dt!"
)
endlocal
```

**After having verified the correct output, remove the upper-case `ECHO` command from the code to actually rename files.**

Answer (score 0):

If the unwanted parts in your file names are space separated a simple:

```
@Echo off
For /F "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B/A-D "-backup- powerpoint*"'
) Do For /f "tokens=2" %%B in ("%%A") Do Echo Ren "%%A" "%%B"
```

Should do (independent of the extension).

```
Ren "-backup- powerpoint1.ppt" "powerpoint1.ppt"
Ren "-backup- powerpoint2.ppt" "powerpoint2.ppt"
Ren "-backup- powerpoint3.ppt" "powerpoint3.ppt"
```